# Filter On Google map on visualforce page salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I have one VF page in that it opens a Google map which displays near by Accounts depending on user's location. On that Google map I have to add a filter to show the account depending on condition(My accounts, My teams Accounts,All Accounts) Can any one Suggest?

```
<!-- Include in Google's Maps API via JavaScript static resource -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.googleMapsAPI}" /> 



<!-- Setup the map to take up the whole window --> 
<style>
    html, body { height: 100%; }
    .page-map, .ui-content, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height:100%; padding: 0; }
    #map-canvas { height: min-height: 100%; }
</style>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var lat, lon;

         // If we can, get the position of the user via device geolocation
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                 lat = position.coords.latitude;
                 lon = position.coords.longitude;                    

                 // Use Visualforce JavaScript Remoting to query for nearby warehouses      
                 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.FindNearbyExt.getNearby}', lat, lon,
                     function(result, event){
                         if (event.status) {
                             console.log(result);
                             createMap(lat, lon, result);           
                         } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                             //exception case code          
                         } else {

                         }
                      }, 
                      {escape: true}
                  );
              });
          } else {
              // Set default values for map if the device doesn't have geolocation capabilities
                /** San Francisco **/
                lat = 37.77493;
                lon = -122.419416;

                var result = [];
                createMap(lat, lon, result);
          }

     }

     function createMap(lat, lon, warehouses){
        // Get the map div, and center the map at the proper geolocation
        var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: currentPosition, 
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Set a marker for the current location
        var positionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: currentPosition,
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'
        });


        // Keep track of the map boundary that holds all markers
        var mapBoundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        mapBoundary.extend(currentPosition);

        // Set markers on the map from the @RemoteAction results
        var warehouse;
        for(var i=0; i<warehouses.length;i++){
            warehouse = warehouses[i];
            console.log(warehouses[i]);
            setupMarker();
        }

        // Resize map to neatly fit all of the markers
        map.fitBounds(mapBoundary);

       function setupMarker(){ 
            var warehouseNavUrl;

            // Determine if we are in Salesforce1 and set navigation link appropriately
            try{
                if(sforce.one){
                    warehouseNavUrl = 
                        'javascript:sforce.one.navigateToSObject(\'' + warehouse.Id + '\')';
                }
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                warehouseNavUrl = '\\' + warehouse.Id;
            }

            var warehouseDetails = 
                '<a href="' + warehouseNavUrl + '">' + 
                warehouse.Name + '</a><br/>' + 
                warehouse.Street_Address__c + '<br/>' + 
                warehouse.City__c + '<br/>' + 
                warehouse.Phone__c;

           // Create the callout that will pop up on the marker     
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
               content: warehouseDetails
           });

           // Place the marker on the map   
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               map: map,
               position: new google.maps.LatLng( 
                               warehouse.Location__Latitude__s, 
                               warehouse.Location__Longitude__s)
           });
           mapBoundary.extend(marker.getPosition());

           // Add the action to open up the panel when it's marker is clicked      
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
           });
       }
    }

    // Fire the initialize function when the window loads
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<!--  All content is rendered by the Google Maps code -->
<!--  This minimal HTML justs provide a target for GMaps to write to -->
<body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

****************************************************

Apex class

```
public FindNearby(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) { }

@RemoteAction
// Find warehouses nearest a geolocation
global static List<Warehouse__c> getNearby(String lat, String lon) {

    // If geolocation isn't set, use San Francisco
    if(lat == null || lon == null || lat.equals('') || lon.equals('')) {
        lat = '37.77493';
        lon = '-122.419416';
    }

    // SOQL query to get the nearest warehouses
    String queryString =
        'SELECT Id, Name, Location__Longitude__s, Location__Latitude__s, ' +
            'Street_Address__c, Phone__c, City__c ' +
        'FROM Warehouse__c ' +
        'WHERE DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') < 20 ' +
        'ORDER BY DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') ' +
        'LIMIT 10';

    // Run and return the query results
    return(database.Query(queryString));
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? Any code? In general you need to set markers depending on the passed geo-data. Normally it is a simple for-loop.

Comment: Vf page has been created to open Google map to show near by accounts. Now I want to add Filter on Google map

Comment: I think you need to add some of your code to the question.

Comment: Post your code please